# How to access server logs

Tags: windows-server-2003, log-files

I'm running Windows Server 2003, and I noticed that when shutting down or etc, the server asks for a reason, and I'm wondering where I can see this information later? Like history or logs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Event Viewer, pull up the System log and filter for event ID 1074. Those are the planned shutdown log entries, and include the text entered in the shutdown dialogue. The [Microsoft KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/293814) has more information for your viewing pleasure.